The vertices of a graph with degree less than three are iteratively removed and the result is a joining of complete graphs and stars
I'm guessing that if I processed a graph by pairing it down in the following way then I would eventually get a bunch of complete graphs and stars joined together. By star I mean a sort of extraneous vertex that might connect multiple parts of the graph, but doesn't connect to any other stars. So, its adjacency are all in the connected graphs that are expected to remain.
Steps:

Repeat removing vertices of degree one until none remain
Remove vertices of degree two

I think that the first step will get rid of anything that looks like a tree, and the second step gets rid of stuff that looks like a path, or cycle.
I don't know any of the graph theory proof techniques, so if anyone could point me in the right direction then I'd appreciate it.

Technically, every graph is a bunch of (1-vertex) complete graphs joined together. But if you mean a stronger statement, I bet that the Petersen graph is a counterexample.

That's right, it is! I've heard it's a counterexample to many conjectures. I should have looked there first.

This procedure yields the 3-core of the graph. Look up k-core decomposition.

Thank you so much. I was able to find a graph theory handbook which mentions them.
